# How to get user story bythe given task in SDK2.0

Tags: rally

I'm creating a grid based on "Task" Model, but I need to show the user story's information like formatted Id and name etc

I have gone throught the doc but couldn't find a user story field in task model.

Just wondering how can I do something like:

```
columnCfgs : [

{ text : 'User Story Id',
  DataIndex : 'userStory.FormattedId'
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field you're looking for is called WorkProduct, since Tasks may also be associated to other types in addition to stories (test sets, defects, etc.)

Comment: thanks Kyle. This is what I need. however, if I write a filter and need something like { property : 'task.WorkProduct.WorkPackge', operation : '=', value : workPackage}, where 'WorkPackge' is specific field for hierachicalRequirement, how can I write this filter?

Comment: If WorkPackage is a custom field then just remember to include the custom prefix c_.   {property: 'WorkProduct.c_WorkPackage', value: 'something'}

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I just came back to this issue today from another work and have tried to use c_ prefix. However, it seems not working as expected. The filter that I used is as below:

Comment: filters : [ {
     property : 'TimeEntryItem.WorkProduct.c_WorkPackage',
     operation : '=',
     value : me.workPackageComboBox.getRecord().get('_ref')
    } ],

Comment: hmm, interesting.  are you getting errors from web services api or is it just not returning any data?

Comment: it's just not returning any data. If this is not working, I'll have to query for each user story for many many times. which is not feasiable at all.

Comment: Actually "WorkPackage" is not a custom field but a  normal field in HierarchicalRequirement. However, "WorkProduct" is a SchedulableArtifact type instead of HierarchicalRequirement. Therefore, "WorkProduct.WorkPackage" is not a valid filter property. Any idea to get around?

Comment: hmm, that's a tricky one.  you may need to just query for all stories with the desired WorkPackage value and then populate all the tasks on those stories.  there is an example here that does something similar with defects: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2-section-collection-fetching

Comment: In my case, the number of user stories could be over 100 and so will be number of queries for tasks for each user story. since there is no "In" operator that can be used, seems that I'm coming to an dead end. BTW, I have also tried to combine multiple filters together with "Or" method. Unfortunately when the number of filters increases over 100, rally sdk throws errors.

Comment: yes, you'll eventually blow out the maximum request size with a huge or'ed together filter like that.  unfortunately i'm not sure there is a great answer here...